# Facebook Authentication API error: Method not found

Tags: facebook, nuget, aspnetboilerplate

I am trying to implement the Facebook authentication. I have upgraded all the Nuget packages for Abp to 2.1.3 except Abp.Castle.Log4Net.

Getting error

```
Error: Method not found:
'Void Abp.Authorization.AuthorizationHelperExtensions.Authorize(Abp.Authorization.IAuthorizationHelper, System.Reflection.MethodInfo)'
```

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded a fresh template of ASP.NET Boilerplate and upgraded all Abp.* nuget packages to v2.2.1 and it resolved the runtime error. I got another error will post that in seperate thread.